# Can we test any and every app on DeviceAnyWhere?

Tags: mobile

Let's say i have an app on BB, Android, iPhone and Windows Mobile.

So can we test apps developed on any platform on DeviceAnyWhere? Please confirm.
Here's the link: http://www.deviceanywhere.com/

Comment: You already know and have the answer, It is all on their website. If you don't believe their site what makes you believe random people on stack overflow.

Comment: I like to seek industry opinion about the product.Wonder if they have a competitor in the market?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, yes. The most popular devices available will be on DA. I've tested an app on about 20 different phones, from Nokia, Blackberry, iPhone, Droid and the likes.

Furthermore, the devices are 'actual' devices - not emulators which is great. You might find some of them sluggish though - testing has proven tedious in previous experiences.

Comment: So that means it is more economical to have DeviceAnyWhere as a testing platform than to buy different devices from time to time?

Comment: That kinda depends on your requirements really, if you're going to have someone (or a team) testing every day, it might pay off to buy phones, thus saving in the longer run. If you only do a few projects a month, you should maybe consider DA. Plus also remember that it'll depend on how many devices you're testing on, if you have to buy 30 different phones, that'll set you back a bit. But you should also consider the fact that DA is not 100% like using a real device, it can be sluggish at times and I've sometimes found it a bit tedious to use.

Comment: What kind of apps/sites will you be testing?

Comment: We'll be testing games, utility apps and database applications on iPhone, Android and BB. What do you say...would it be good for us to use DeviceAnyWhere?

Comment: I can see testing games being a pain to be honest, it's not real time so I'm not even sure how you would play it. Go for actual devices than I guess - or get a trial account with DA and see if it meets your needs.

Comment: Wonder if there aren't any other players in the market in mobile apps testing? Thanks

Comment: I don't know of any other ones sorry